# CSS: Align a textarea inside a td

Tags: html, css

it's one of those usual table-related questions. I am trying to bloody align a textarea to be centered in a  table element. It just won't work... I feel like I have tried everything...

Do you need a sample code for something like this? Just imagine this:

```
<table>
<td><textarea></textarea></td>
</table>
```

The task is to align the textarea in the center of this td.

Comment: "I feel like I have tried everything" what exactly? Giving a width and setting auto-margin for left and right should work—but you doubtless tried that…

Comment: I tried margin left and right at auto and display: block

Comment: You need to specify a width too. See @Subdigger's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

css

```
textarea {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. Why do you need to specify a width? That's what I hadn't included. Why is it needed?

Comment: @devilwontcry it does not (and height also). just example

Comment: It didn't work without it... -.- 
CSS can be so weird and complicated when having to do with tables... I hate these structures...

Answer (score 3):

only centered ?

```
<table>
<td valign="middle" align="center"><textarea></textarea></td>
</table>
```

or do you want fill the whole td ?

Comment: It does. It looks like you have some specific case in which it does not work. Is your TD wide enough?

Comment: yes it does, thanks for the downvote before testing / asking.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
td {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I said I have tried everything... you think I wouldn't have thought of that?

Comment: Hence the word *should* in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

set height and line-height properties.
style="width: 100%;height:885px; font-family: Sans-Serif; font-size: 11px; line-height:22px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"